# Simple example of using ffmpeg to convert a movie into a format that can be viewed on Apple products

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I have a directory of AVI and MOV movies taken from my digital camera. I'd like to write a Python script to go through them, and for every AVI or MOV it finds, generate a file in place that can be viewed on Apple products (iPad, Apple TV, etc ...). My videos are 1080p, and I'm interested in preserving as much of the original quality as possible.

Any examples of how to do this with ffmpeg? Specifically, flags to pass to the executable? Would I want to do a one or two-pass encoding (what's the difference?)

I'm hoping to do the scripting part in Python.

Answer (score 1):

Well the device screens are much smaller than 1080p. So there is no point in trying to display a 1080p video on a 720p screen. Best is you have a couple of profiles. One for large screens and one for the smaller ones.

For a single stream to play across you need baseline profile single reference frame H.264.
If the streams are to play from a server you create hls files. If they are to be played locally I think mp4 should suffice.

```
ffmpeg -i <input> -acodec aac -strict -2 -b:a <audio bitrate> -profile baseline -s <widthxheight> -b:v <video bitrate> -pass 1 output.mp4
```

Followed by same command but pass set to 2

The above is sufficient to create videos. Two pass is better than 1 because encoder gets a second chance to look at the content and in first pass it would have gathered some statistics.

Google around a bit for some other flags. Plenty of examples out there. The ones above should work though. Replace the < > parts with the values you want

here's an actual example: ffmpeg -i input.ts -acodec aac -strict -2 -b:a 128k -profile baseline -s 320x240 -b:v 2000k -pass 1 output.mp4